Old cartoon movie from late 80's / early 90's with a flying ship
I can remember snippets of this movie I saw as a kid. It was either Claymation or animation and I remember a lot of orange tones. It was about some sort of creature that went on an adventure in a flying ship. I remember the sound of the propellers on the flying ship and it flew over these volcanoes which pulsed out as they erupted. 
For some reason I have it in my mind that it may have been Australian - however I can't find anything like it from Australia or anywhere else. I don't think there were any Australia specific creatures in it (kangaroo's, Koala's etc).
From what I remember, they weren't superheroes; there was a main character who was a made up creature I think - not like an animal or dragon or unicorn or anything. I think there may have been another character, possibly also on the flying ship and I feel that at times they were trying to escape from someone or something.
I know it does exist as in the early 2001-ish I was working at a video store and sold the VHS copy to a customer. If I wrote down what the title was, it's long gone.I've been trying to remember this for years. It would be great if someone had any ideas I could pursue. Thanks

Can you provide any more details like, what they did like they were superheros or mystery solvers

From what I remember, they weren't superhero's there was a main character who was a made up creature  I think - not like an animal or dragon or unicorn or anything. Memory is very sketchy though. I think there may have been another character, possibly also on the flying ship and I feel that at times they were trying to escape from someone or something... Not very helpful I'm sure.

Was the lava in different colors?

I think you're after the animated 80s Australian film The Phantom Treehouse.

Two Australian children [Tom and Lucy] chase a cat and a dog into a swamp near their homes. Here they find a treehouse which they never noticed before. Inside the treehouse is a trapdoor which brings them to a wild and wonderful world with pirates, talking trees and bunyips!

The creature you mentioned is a bunyip. At one point, while trying to rescue Lucy from a pirate ship, Tom and his dog are in an airship and fly over volcanoes that shoot out lava in different colors.
The entire movie is currently available on Youtube. Here are some clips, and  you can see the airship and volcanoes around the minute mark:




That's amazing, thank you. I hadn't remembered the human characters though on seeing the clip I do remeber Tom and Lucy and the sound of the airsip was exactly how it played in my memory. I'm pleasently surprised someone worked it out based on my rather meagre description! Very satisfying, thank you.
